# dependent picklist not getting populated while creating a record using force:createRecord Lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-events

I am trying to open a record create page on click of a button on the Account detail page in lightning. I have created a lightning component and a controller as follows.

The dependent picklist isn't getting populated. Here `Child_Field__c` is the dependent picklist for the  `Parent_field__c`.The values will be available from an apex class.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" access="global"/>
```

Controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
         var createEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
                createEvent.setParams({
                    "entityApiName": "Test_Object__c",
                    "defaultFieldValues": {
                        Name        : 'Test Record1',
                        Description__c  :'test description',
                        Parent_field__c : 'a',
                        Child_Field__c  : '1',
                        additional_field__c : 'q'
                    }
                });
                createEvent.fire(); 
    }
})
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Shweta, I am looking to implement similar functionality. Is this issue still existing or is there any work around for this. Thanks.